# Failing to catch the row that specifies the location of an error with a TryCatch

Tags: r, error-handling

I would like to catch problematic rows that result from an error in the code below.
In actual data, I get the error message:

```
Warning message:
In right_join(., strat_dat, by = "idnr") :
  Each row in `x` is expected to match at most 1 row in `y`.
ℹ Row 4987 of `x` matches multiple rows.
ℹ If multiple matches are expected, set `multiple = "all"` to silence this warning.
```

This my example code:

```
library(dplyr)

# create example data frames
df_bm <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("1", "2", "3"))
strat_dat <- data.frame(idnr = c(11,22,22,33), mem = c("ja", "nee", "ja", "nee"))

# function to catch error and store problematic rows
catch_error <- function() {
  tryCatch(
    {
      df_bm <- df_bm %>%
        mutate(idnr = as.numeric(paste0(b, a)), .before = a) %>%
        right_join(strat_dat, by = "idnr") %>%
        filter(mem == "ja") %>%
        select(-c(a, b, mem))
    },
    warning = function(w) {
      message(paste("Warning:", w$message))
      rows <- which(duplicated(df_bm$idnr))
      rows_out <<- rows
      message(paste("Problematic rows:", toString(rows)))
    }
  )
}

# run the function
catch_error()
```

Has the following output:

```
Warning: Each row in `x` is expected to match at most 1 row in `y`.
Problematic rows:
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The issue is that the `df_bm` does does not have a column named `idnr`. You are creating this column and assigning the result to *another* variable named `df_bm`, but that assignment happens at a time when the `warning` function has already executed and thus refers to the previous value of `df_bm`.

Comment: I get no warning...